# CSS: Stretch divs to fit width, ONLY IF they are within each other's y-axis space

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqatj.png

^^^
This picture is an idea of what I'm looking for

More info:

- I am looking to have multiple divs that would overlap instead fit to the width equally
- From the picture, div 1 has nothing next to it, so it expands to the full width of the wrapper
- div 2 and div 3 are next to each other, so they both shrink to 50% to fit the width.
- if a div 4 was introduced invading the space of div 2 or div 3, then those 3 divs would shrink to 33% width and so on.
- The divs need to be positioned using "top:" from css, so I am trying to have their position be absolute or relative or something else that would allow that.

Here's some code from the actual project:

```
<div class="schedule-body">

<div class="hours">

<div>12:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>1:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>2:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>3:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>4:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>5:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>6:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>7:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>8:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>9:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>10:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>11:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>12:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>1:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>2:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>3:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>4:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>5:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>6:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>7:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>8:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>9:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>10:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>
<div>11:00pm<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>

</div>

<div class="events"></div>

</div>


.events {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 5%;
width: 75%;
height: calc( 20% * 24 );
z-index: 2;
display: flex;
justify-content: stretch;
}

.events div {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba( 0, 188, 140, .5 );
border-radius: 0.5rem;
z-index: 2;
box-shadow: 0 0 2rem .4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding-top: 5%;
font-size: 1rem;
justify-content: center;
}
```

- the div: events, is on a z-index of 2 so it is above the hours but still within the schedule-body
- .events div refers to divs that will be added to the events box, these are the ones that need to stretch and fit the width of each other.
- I am attempting to use display: flex and justify-content: stretch in order to make this work, but the divs all stretch even if they don't overlap on the y-axis.

  - For example, from the picture attatched, div 1, div 2, div 3 would all be 33% even though div 1 wouldn't overlap with div 2 or div 3.
- I have also tried adding flex: 1 to the .events div but that didn't work either

I have a general idea of why this is all happening but I'm not sure how to fix this. I have done lots of looking around but can't find any answers to this specific scenario.

If it helps at all, this is all for a side-project I'm working on for myself, making an organizer application and this is the schedule, where events will show up and overlapping events will fit the width properly instead of cutting each other off.

I appreciate any advice, thank you!

Comment: Something like this might be possible with CSS, but you'd have much more control over it with JS. Are you ok using it?

Comment: Have a look at this, it would probably make your life much easier! https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Jack I am okay with JS, I recently just learned about Electron and Bootstrap so that's what inspired me to start this project. So I just kinda picked up JS, the issue is more of just know what to research to make this happen.

Comment: @LaurentC I will check our masonry and attempt to implement that to see if it can help me! I will most likely use it as a last resort if I cannot find another solution however, I'd like to stay as close to vanilla as possible for the moment so I can gain a better understanding of the limits and capabilities of CSS and JS.

Comment: oh, please correct your code `<hr>` has NO closing tag

Comment: @black blue There is a closing tag, I usually leave whitespace but this time so it can be tough to see

Comment: `<div>11:00pm<hr class = "hours-half">` **</hr>**  `</div>`

Comment: @black blue Yes, I posted <div>12:00am<hr class = "hours-half"></hr></div>, maybe stack overflow isn't showing it properly?

Comment: me again - I'm not native English, and I was in a bad mood - tag `<hr>` is `self-closing` - its closing tag doesn't exists in html, I hope you understand - don't use closing tags if they not exists because it is a bug; it won't happen if you start to use https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your willing to use JavaScript you could try something like this

```js
function assignWidths() {
  let rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    let row = rows[i],
        cellWidth = 100 / row.childElementCount;

    for (let c = 0; c < row.childElementCount; c++) {
        row.children[c].style.width = cellWidth + '%';
    }
  }
}

function addEle() {
  document.querySelector('.row').innerHTML += '<div>Cell</div>';
  
  assignWidths();
}

function removeEle() {
  let row = document.querySelector('.row');
  row.removeChild(row.lastChild);
  
  assignWidths();
}

assignWidths();
```

```css
.row {
  width: 500px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  font-size: 0px;
}

.row > div {
  display: inline-block;
  
  font-size: 18px;
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div>Cell</div><div>Cell</div><div>Cell</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="addEle()">Add Element</button>
<button onclick="removeEle()">Remove Element</button>
```

This script will find all elements with the class `row` and then make each of the children the appropriate width each time `assignWidths()` is called. `addEle()` and `removeEle()` are just for demonstration.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought about the idea of using some type of assign Width function I was just worried about how much it would slow down the program. Thank you!

Comment: @NikoNikolopoulos You shouldn't see any performance effects untill thousands of elements and by then somthing other than this script will probably cause more lag. Only performance issue I see is if it's called every time the window resizes with hundreds of elements.

Comment: Ah I really appreciate this! I was able to make an assignWidths function that fits my project. I appreciate your advice and input.